# SQL - Inner join on two columns from table 1 with one column from table 2?

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have a table that has two columns that each contain a member id that is a foreign key to a members table that contains their name. I want to select the first table with names instead of member IDs. I'm not sure of a way to do this. I feel like there's certainly a way involving an INNER JOIN, but I can't think of how to pick two names from one table in one INNER JOIN. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Match table

```
|------|-------|
| user | match |
|------|-------|
| 1    | 4     |
| 2    | 1     |
| 3    | 2     |
|------|-------|
```

Members table

```
|------|-------|
| user | name  |
|------|-------|
| 1    | Joe   |
| 2    | Kyle  |
| 3    | John  |
| 4    | Nate  |
|------|-------|
```

Desired output

```
|------|-------|
| user | match |
|------|-------|
| Joe  | Nate  |
| Kyle | Joe   |
| John | Kyle  |
|------|-------|
```

Comment: No, you can't do this in one join.  You're going to need one reference to `Match`, and _two_ to `Member`.  Does that give you a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should join members table for twice.

```
SELECT M1.NAME , M2.NAME
FROM MEMBERS M1
INNER JOIN MATCH M
   ON M1.USER = M.USER
INNER JOIN MEMBERS M2
   ON M2.USER = M.MATCH
```

Be carefull with lower and upper identifiers if your database is mysql.

Comment: I am trying to use this example in a problem I am currently having but I cant figure out what all the Ms are,  Can you please a more detailed description of the code?

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with an Outer Apply: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f932/5

```
SELECT me.name as 'User',
  mem.name as 'Match'
FROM Match m
OUTER APPLY(
  SELECT me.name
  FROM Members me
  WHERE me.id = m.match
)mem
LEFT JOIN Members me on me.id = m.id
```

Or: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f932/6

```
SELECT me.name as 'User',
  mem.name as 'Match'
FROM Match m
LEFT JOIN Members mem on mem.id = m.match
LEFT JOIN Members me on me.id = m.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do two joins:

```
SELECT u1.name, u2.name
FROM members u1
INNER JOIN match m
ON u1.user = m.user
INNER JOIN members u2
ON u2.user = m.match
```